# Change CSS of div when next to certain Divs

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change CSS based on where it is located. I have dynamic positioning based on where the user wants to put the appropriate div. For example, I have a twitter div that has `margin:40px 0;` Like so:

[image]

However when it is positioned at the bottom next to the footer I wish it to have

```
margin:40px 0 0 0;
```

This is to remove this gap:

[image]

So I want only certain container divs css to change based on their position next to another the footer or the header. Is this possible? I hope this is clear.

I cannot provide code as there is 7 container divs sorted via PHP breaks depending where the user places that block. If it is NEXT to the footer or header div I need it to not have the margin. So

```
<header></header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="information"></div>
    <div class="block-1"></div>
    <div class="block-1"></div>
    <div class="block-1"></div>
    <div class="block-1"></div>
    <div class="block-1"></div>
    <div class="twitter"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comment and edit, you may want to use the first child and last child selector:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

```
.twitter { margin: 40px 0; }
.container .twitter:first-child, .container .twitter:last-child { margin: 40px 0 0 0; }
```

so that if the twitter is the first or last child inside `.container`, then use that specific style.

Or

```
.twitter { margin: 40px 0; }
.container .twitter:first-child, .container .twitter:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

this way, you don't need to change `40px` at 2 places if you decide to make it `42px` later.  You will only need to change it at 1 place.

Or if you just want the twitter div not have the margin under the header or above the footer, then

```
.twitter { margin: 40px 0; }
.container .twitter:first-child { margin-top: 0; } 
.container .twitter:last-child  { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: maybe i didn't make myself clear but it is not within the footer. There is 7 container divs sorted via PHP breaks depending where the user places that block. If it is NEXT to the footer or header div I need it to not have the margin